# Tortoise SVN auto lock

Tags: tortoisesvn

Is there a way to have tortoise svn automatically lockdown files when you check them out, with out having to check them out and then lock down the files you want?

Also, is there a way to not allow other people to checkout any files if they are locked down? Right now it lets them checkout the locked files, edit them, and then when they go to commit the files it gives them an error that they are locked.

Thanks!

Comment: You are using the wrong tool. SVN was designed for concurrent, collaborative hacking: Everyone can change everything at any type, but can only check in after they have updated to the latest change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is sort of a non-answer, but Subversion (SVN) isn't a Lock-Modify-Unlock system, it's a Copy-Modify-Merge system, although it does provide the locking feature for stuff that can't be readily merged (like images, certain types of datasets, Office documents, etc).

In general, you don't want to restrict developers from having the ability to modify chunks of source code as it leads to all sorts of versioning, semantic incompatibility, and work concurrency problems between developers. If you're trying to lock source code, I highly suggest you reread Subversion or TortoiseSVN's help documentation to better understand how and why this is the case. Tortoise's built in help is really superb (available from the TortoiseSVN context menu).

Comment: this is wrong, what about binaries?